# Snooping Around the Garbage

Tags: story

So you're a spy for ACorp, which is snooping around in the BCorp (competitor) garbage truck. You just found a note that might've had their computer system password; however, where's the username?

The note is...

> **SECRET PASSWORD!!!!!!**
>   IS
>   U &^% **& %%# ## P #!!! )#( $$$#^ &*^ ## # ^^& %)! ! @@ ( @ # #!! !@@## #
>   WP:WP:5P5 no rules, just please keep the s harp. Oh, and keep the really spacey coworker Bob, too! Just dump this (and everything else in my office) in the GARBAGE!!!

(Don't worry, they aren't words, they're the actual characters.)